# Search Controller issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, search

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];**

    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.FeeSchedule.text = _Fschedule[row];
    cell.NonFS.text = _Nonfeeschedule[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [medicalCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [medicalCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailviewcontroller = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        int row = [myIndexPath row];
        detailviewcontroller.DetailModal = @[_Title[row],_Description[row],_Fschedule[row],_Nonfeeschedule[row],_Images[row]];
    }
}

`enter code here`- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    searchResults = [medicalCodes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}
```

I have a problem, I am trying to get my search bar to work, however it is stoping at this point right here essentially causing the app to crash. I am open to any suggestions as to any ways to add a search bar better. Any suggestions on what I can do?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you should update your data in Main thread

Comment: Give the crash log please

Comment: did you reload tableview any where

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x30c10f03 0x3b57fce7 0x30b47331 0x2973d5 0x336f9e01 0x336a115b 0x336a09b1 0x335c7185 0x3324312b 0x3323e94f 0x3326d95d 0x33643617 0x33641c21 0x33640e5f 0x33640de7 0x33640d7f 0x33639481 0x335cd50f 0x33640ad1 0x336405a5 0x335d2485 0x335cfc49 0x33639851 0x336364f5 0x33630ad9 0x335ccb0f 0x335cbc71 0x33630215 0x35c80b55 0x35c8073f 0x30bdb83f 0x30bdb7db 0x30bd9fa7 0x30b447a9 0x30b4458b 0x3362f43b 0x3362a6d9 0x298379 0x3ba99ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: Well, that error will be thrown at you for lot of reasons. I would suggest you to inspect the call stack! Set an all-exceptions breakpoint in Xcode (press the "+" button at the bottom of the breakpoints pane in the navigator.) Then when the exception occurs you'll drop into the debugger. You can use the "bt" command to log a backtrace. Of course, you can find this trace in debug navigator.

Comment: guess what I should be asking is, what is the best way to implement a search bar into my app. I have 8800 + codes in 3 different arrays, One is for medical codes, one is for the description and one is for images. I have followed 2 tutiorials online with no luck, if anyone could guide me in the right direction that would be much appreciated. Thanks again for your help. This is the only thing holding me back from getting in the app store. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are update your data in main thread

or

if you are reload your tableview update with UI Main thread

```
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
              [self.tableView reloadData]
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your code here, you are configuring cell even before allocating it.
And the codes you've written after following line will go untouched since you are returning the call.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [medicalCodes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  return cell;
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. But I would suggest you try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";
    TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
                                                      forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //you can also allocate your custom cell here and then configure it as your need.
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.TitleLabel.text = _Title[row];
    cell.DescriptionLabel.text = _Description[row];
    cell.FeeSchedule.text = _Fschedule[row];
    cell.NonFS.text = _Nonfeeschedule[row];
    cell.ThumbImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_Images[row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = medicalCodes[indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```